# RegEx to omit specific words in between strings

Tags: regex, atom-editor

I want to retrieve names from this string, but it shouldn't consume `" and "s` using RegEx.

```
author={GenTSCH, JoN R and Glass, RI and Woods, P and Gouvea, V and Gorziglia, M and Flores, J and Das, BK and Bhan, MK}
```

so far I have written `(?<author={).*(?=})`, but it is capturing all the string inside `{}`

I am running RegEx in atom editor to capture strings in a file.

My desired output is selecting the entire string inside brackets except for `\sand\s`.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/D51YLQ/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew you might be regex wizard. Thanks

Comment: indeed, @WiktorStribiżew is a regex.pert :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit to @Wiktor for the pattern!  This works... and while getting to it learned that python **regex module is different from re module** *(the latter is in standard library, which is what I suspect regex101 uses :o)*

```
import regex
pattern = r"(?:author={|\G(?!\A)\s+and\s+)\K(?:(?!\sand\s)[^{}])+"
test_str = "author={GenTSCH, JoN R and Glass, RI and Woods, P and Gouvea, V and Gorziglia, M and Flores, J and Das, BK and Bhan, MK}"
print(regex.findall(pattern, test_str))  

##  ['GenTSCH, JoN R', 'Glass, RI', 'Woods, P', 'Gouvea, V', 'Gorziglia, M', 'Flores, J', 'Das, BK', 'Bhan, MK']
```

Comment: Hi, No, I am just looking for a pattern.

Comment: so just selection/matching of everything except all the " and "s?

Comment: Yes. @wiktor answered the question above.